# BSOD, failed automatic backup and internal drives suddenly showing up as "removable" on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, motherboard, backup, bsod

I've started experiencing BSOD on my Windows 7 computer.

Usually the BSOD does not have any details but one of them had the **KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE error.**

I thought it was probably a disk or the RAM so I ran chkdsk (and repair) on all drives and a full MemTest86 test but still getting the BSOD.

But then I realized that my **automatic windows backup** (backing up my SSD C: drive to my SATA D: drive) **was not working anymore**. The reason given by Windows: **"Your destination drive is not valid. You cannot use a volume included in the back as a destination"**.

[image]

So I was like "meh?? I've being doing this for years (literally)". So I clicked the "Modify backup parameters" which opens up the list of available destination drives. And when I choose my D: drive, Windows tells me that I cannot use this drive because"**Planned backup of the system image is not allowed on removable devices**".

[image]

Meh again !!! So I check the bottom right **"unplug" icon and all of my drives (including the SSD C: drive which runs Windows) are here !** I'm pretty sure there were not here before !!!

I also had a glance at the Events Viewer but didn't find anything obvious there (a few errors but nothing very clear).

Before the BSOD, **I had to open the computer box to replug the box fan** (which was starting on boot up then stopping a few minutes later for no reason). And I feel like the BSOD started a little later after that. Note that the fan is working fine now so I assumed it was just a loose cable.

Could this be me touching something I shouldn't have when opening the box? What can I try ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The error `KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE` is related to hardware problems.
It comes with an important code with defines the reason for the error
(you might also be able to find it in the Event Viewer).

Some common error codes:

- 0x0000007A: File access errors
- 0xC000009C: Bad hard drive sectors
- 0xC000009D: Loose cables or hard disk failure
- 0xC000016A: Bad hard drive sectors
- 0xC0000185: Unseated or damaged cables

You should find out more information about the hardware error.
As the computer came with Windows 7, it's certainly not new,
so some error has arisen, which is not necessarily connected to the fan.

---

For the specific problem of internal disks being marked as removable,
here is one workaround counseled by Microsoft in
[Internal SATA Drives show up as removeable media](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/internal-sata-drives-show-up-as-removeable-media-1f806a64-8661-95a6-adc7-ce65a976c8dd):

- Run the Device Manager
- Under Disk Drives, identify the disk
- Right-click the disk and select Properties
- Note the Bus Number (B) and port number (N) of Target ID

  [image]
- Run the Command Prompt (CMD) as Administrator
- Enter this command:

  ```
  reg.exe add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\msahci\ControllerB\ChannelN\" /f /v TreatAsInternalPort /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000001
  ```

  Where B and N correspond to the above.
- Reboot.

You will find more details in the article
[Internal SSD/SATA Drive Shows as a Removable in Windows](http://woshub.com/internal-ssd-sata-drive-shows-removable/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the error code I got was 0x0000007A. Any idea what it could be ? On top of that, after updating drivers and the BIOS, my drives don't show up as removable anymore BUT I still can't backup on my D: drive because Windows thinks it's a start drive/has Windows installed. Feels like it's definitely my D: drive being faulty here.

Comment: Consult the SMART data of the disk (if it's not too old for SMART).

Comment: all good in crystalkdiskinfo. No BSOD so far after my changes

Comment: If you have other backups than D: (1) Delete the backup job and recreate it, and if this doesn't help:  (2) Delete the backup job again and slow format D (not quick format). Be careful, in case D is truly now required for the boot. So before format I would advice to disconnect D physically and seeing if booting can still succeed.

Comment: Good advice thanks for that I'll give it a try

Comment: fixed the problem, I've posted the detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I managed to fix my problems, here's the deal.

**Regarding the disks being marked as removable**

I've done the following:

- checked the disks' health using CrystalDiskInfo (no problem)
- then I've looked up for all the available drivers (including motherboard and chipsets drivers), installed them.
- on top of that, I've updated my BIOS

After doing all that, the disks were back in their "normal" state but still couldn't launch a backup.

**Regarding Windows not letting me backing up**

After the first step, the backup still wouldn't run because :

> The backup storage location is invalid. You cannot use a volume that
> is included in the backup as a storage location. (error code:
> 0X80780040)

I was 100% sure no operating system was installed on my destination drive. So I assumed it was something else. I ended up installing AdvancedWinServiceManager to check the locations of all the services installed on my machine and boom, I've found the two culprits:

- first one was **VirtualBox**, which I installed a year ago on my destination drive but comes up with a service.
- second one was a app that was installed through a software called Overwolf (a gaming app).

After deleting those two, my backup works again.

**Regarding the BSOD**

It's too early to tell yet, but I feel like fixing the first problem helped with that. I'm keeping a eye on temperatures and events but so far so good.

Thanks for the help